# how can i set the dns of the node js server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking, dns

I want to set the primary dns , secondary dns of node js server.

But i use 'setup' module , there are only dns , not secondary dns.

Like this

```
var setup = require('setup')();

var config = setup.network.config({
    wlan0: {
        auto: true, // start at Boot
        dhcp: true, // Use DHCP
        wireless: {
            ssid: 'myWirelessName', // Wireless SSID
            psk: 'mySuperPassword', // Password
        }
    },
   eth0: {
        auto: true,
       ipv4: {
            address: '192.168.1.20',
            netmask: '255.255.255.0',
            gateway: '192.168.1.1',
            dns: '8.8.8.8'
       }
    }
});
```

how can i set primary dns and secondary dns of the node js?

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: You are more likely to get help if you go to this module's github, and create an issue there. here is the link to this module's issues page - https://github.com/hugorodrigues/setup/issues

Comment: Don't you set a DNS on your server at the OS level or at your gateway/router?  Are you really trying to set a DNS configuration for one node.js app?

Comment: @jfriend00 yes i want to set primary dns and secondary dns of node.js app

Comment: You mean you want your app to run as DNS server and answer the DNS queries?

Comment: Did you try this: [dns.setServers()](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns_setservers_servers)?.  Also, read: [Implementation Considerations](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_implementation_considerations) and [Two categories of DNS functions](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns).  Some functions in node.js use the underlying DNS capabilities of the operating system so to affect them, you have to change the configuration of the DNS in the OS.

Comment: @jfriend00     i use the dns module , but it was did not changed.   dns.setServers([
    '8.8.8.8', '8.8.4.4']);  Is there anything wrong with the part I wrote?